# Can not create .thumbs directory for /DCIM/Camera/.thumbnails

Tags: android, kotlin

I am programming a gallery and want to store the generated thumbnales for each photo/video in a .thumnails directory. The app works well with all my media in a test directory but fails to create a .thumbnails directors in /storage/0123-4567/DCIM/Camera/

```
val thumbPath = "/storage/0123-4567/DCIM/Camera/.thumbnails"
val success = File(thumbPath ).mkdirs()
val exists = File(thumbPath ).exists()
```

The varabiel success as well as exists are false after this code.
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Why not use /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removable micro sd cards are not writable. –

You have only write access to the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().